# Vim error `undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsWideChar` after installing YouCompleteMe

Tags: python, vim, youcompleteme

I'm trying to install [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) for Vim 7.4 with included patches 1-712 on Ubuntu 15.10.

I have compiled YouCompleteMe by [hand](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#full-installation-guide) since I encountered an error looking like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

As stated in the [FAQ Section](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#i-get-libpython27a--relocation-r_x86_64_32-when-compiling), adding `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so` will solve it. Therefore, compliled it with this instead:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so . ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/cpp
```

then:

```
cmake --build . --target ycm_support_libs --config Release
```

I did not encountered any error while compiling this time but when I open Vim I, I see this instead:

```
   import ycm_client_support
                            ImportError: /home/austin/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_client_support.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsWideChar















Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPython:
line   33:
Traceback (most recent call last):
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPython:
line   33:
  File "<string>", line 29, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPython:
line   33:
  File "/home/austin/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/youcompleteme.py", line 32, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPython:
line   33:
    from ycm.omni_completer import OmniCompleter
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPython:
line   33:
  File "/home/austin/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../python/ycm/omni_completer.py", line 22, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPython:
line   33:
    from ycmd.completers.completer import Completer
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPyth
on:
line   33:
  File "/home/austin/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/../third_party/ycmd/ycmd
/completers/completer.py", line 25, in <module>
Press ENTER or type command to continue
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPyth
on:
line   33:
    from ycm_client_support import FilterAndSortCandidates
Error detected while processing function youcompleteme#Enable..<SNR>64_SetUpPyth
on:
line   33:
ImportError: /home/austin/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycm_client_
support.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_AsWideChar
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue described in the Python FAQ => https://docs.python.org/2/faq/extending.html#when-importing-module-x-why-do-i-get-undefined-symbol-pyunicodeucs2

"The only way to solve this problem is to use extension modules compiled with a Python binary built using the same size for Unicode characters."

It's possible for you to test the size of unicode character of your python with that:

```
import sys
if sys.maxunicode > 65535:
  print 'UCS4 build'
else:
  print 'UCS2 build'
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply since I have school work. I tried testing the size Unicode of my python and it was `UCS4 build` and it needs to be UCS2, am I right? So, do you know exactly what to do?

Comment: Ok, reinstall your python from source (with --prefix=/usr/local to not interfere with the system Python) or build your own deb file from the original Ubuntu package (http://superuser.com/questions/24326/how-to-modify-a-deb-package)

If your reinstall your python from source, use:

'./configure --enable-unicode=ucs2'

to configure the source to build with UCS2 support. (but ucs2 is the default value… therefore it’s not necessary… :s)

Comment: I have reinstalled my python from source and checked if it is a UCS2 build and it is. I added `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/local/bin/python2` to cmake but still get the same error. I think the error is the python interpreter that vim uses since when I checked what the vim uses it was the UCS4 build (my default python).

Comment: OK, great ! :)
Now check your python vim:
``:python import sys; print('UCS4 build' if sys.maxunicode > 65535 else 'UCS2 build')``
Anyway, the best thing to do is compile your vim with your 'new' python system.

Comment: Should I `sudo apt-get remove vim` then `sudo apt-get install vim`? Will it remove the `.vimrc` and all the plugins? (Just to be sure ;) )

Comment: No. ``apt-get remove vim`` will not change your vimrc file.  

For information:  

``apt-get remove packagename``:  
will remove the binaries, but not the configuration or data files of the package packagename. It will also leave dependencies installed with it on installation time untouched.

``apt-get purge packagename`` or ``apt-get remove --purge packagename``:  

will remove about everything regarding the package packagename, but not the dependencies installed with it on installation.